# Need help with Volume question.

Tags: calculus

[image]

I have to find the Area of the Vertical cross section A and the Volume. I have no idea how to do this problem we never learned this in class. Need all the help I can get. Thank you.

Comment: Text is preferred over images when posting questions. Images are impossible to find via search. You help others who are looking for the same answer by posting the text instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that the height $h$ and the base $b$ of a triangle are equal. Since the area of the triangle with base $b$ and height $h$ is $(1/2)bh$, the area of a base equals height triangle is $(1/2)b^2$, where $b$ is the base.

When $x=2$, we have $y^2=25-2^2=21$. So the base "at" $x=2$ is $2\sqrt{21}$, and therefore the area of cross-section is $(1/2)(2^2)(21)$.

In general, the base "at" $x$ of our triangle is $2\sqrt{25-x^2}$. Thus the area $A(x)$ of cross section at $x$ is $(1/2)(2\sqrt{25-x^2})^2$, which simplifies to $2(25-x^2)$.

To find the volume, you will need to integrate $A(x)\,dx$ from the beginning ($x=-5$) to the end ($x=5)$.  It may make life easier to exploit symmetry, integrate from $0$ to $5$, and double the result.

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot. Any idea how I would find the volume?

Comment: It is almost explicitly in the post. The volume is $\int_{-5}^5 2(25-x^2)\,dx$. The integration is easy. I suggested in the post using instead $2\int_0^5 2(25-x^2)\,dx$.