# can you someone help me to draw the picture of this math question ? How it looks like ? the graph

Tags: integration

Find the volume of the solid whose base is the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and the cross sections perpendicular to the x-axis are triangles whose height and base are equal.

Comment: "to the -axis"? I think you accidentally a word.

Comment: I am sorry, I edited that, its says perpendicular to the x-axis.

Comment: Drawing this thing is probably a lot harder than integrating it. Just try to picture a bunch of triangles stacked together, growing from small to big and back small again.

Comment: EuYu, thanks for replying. well, is that the base is in circle shape (whole circle)?, and is it a vertical triangle on top of base ?

Comment: if that is triangle, then which is the circle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I cannot draw. First of all, I recently answered a question about computing the volume in a very similar setting [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300738/need-help-with-volume-question)  It was a circle of radius $5$, and cross-sections perpendicular to the $y$-axis, but adapting the method is routine.

The object is a decorative object, say made of glass. Its base (bottom) is a circle. It is sitting on a table. So draw a circle on the table.

The solid goes upward from the table. Cross-sections perpendicular to the $x$-axis are triangles. So the object will have a sharp spine, say parallel to the $x$-axis: It will be uncomfortable to sit on. The object is highest at the $y$-axis. When you slice downwards there, the cross-section is a triangle with base of length $2$, and therefore height $2$.

The cross-section perpendicular to the $x$-axis at say $x=0.9$, or $x=-0.9$, is much less tall, so the object is quite a bit lower at that point. The whole thing kind of looks like a hedgehog, or a mountain ridge. From the top of the ridge, you can ski downwards in a straight line to the bottom.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I got it.

Comment: Good, I hope my "thousand words" partly made up for the missing picture.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the plot via this URL:

[Check out the plot here.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%20%2b%20y%5E2%20=%201)

Now, to address your question, I shall assume that the cross section is the $y-\text{axis}$. Its length is 2.

Comment: I think the OP is referring to a 3-dimensional structure.

Comment: the question says, the base is circle, and cross section is triangle. I can't figure out the shape of this solid.